# How to run celery and celerybeat from the same command

Tags: celery, pyramid

I have a project which has two `tasks.py` files. The strucutre looks like something like this

```
root/
    webproject
        __init__.py
        models.py
         views.pu
        celerytasks/
            __init__.py
            celeryconfig.py
            tasks.py
    scheduledJobs/
        celeryconfig.py
        tasks.py
```

celerytasks are added by `webrequests` and `scheduledJobs` are well, scheduled jobs for the website (delete old files etc).

I have to run celery twice now from command line. Out code is not production yet, so I am using nohup to do this. My question is can I somehow run both with the same command.

I have just started using celery.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: This is such an old question of mine. :P 

Nah. But I figured out that you have run it has two commands.

Howerver, you could use something like `supervisord` to get a single interface. Once you have it configured right, `supervisorctl restart/stop/start all` will give me a single interface to work with.  Let me know if you would like my sample config file for supervisord.

Comment: That would be much appreciated!

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/RLSx3DMx

Answer (score 1):

I use next arguments: `worker -B`, but better look to documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler.

Comment: Could you explain this? What does the -B do?

Comment: I not sure that can explain better that celery documentation can, however `-B` is option that also start celery beat, that used for running scheduled jobs.